# php not parsed via ssl

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I am in the middle of setting up a VPS based on CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2 with mod_ssl.

My problem is that PHP is not parsing pages served over SSL. My /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf looks like:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/chain.txt

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
<Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
        ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas what would be causing php not to parse over ssl?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what my problem was, maybe this can help someone else. So my SSL Vhost was AllowOverride All while my non-ssl Vhost was AllowOverride None.

When the .htaccess file was enabled via the Vhost AllowOverride All setting, the .htaccess file had one line that was causing PHP to fail: "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php"

This was incorrect and overriding the correct config in php.conf: "AddHandler php5-script .php"